# Как прочитать объект, который находится внутри функции?

Tags: php, классы, объекты

Есть класс, в котором функция, а в ней объект `$photo`
Научите пожалуйста, как "читать" этот объект за пределами функции и класса?!

```
<?php 
require_once '../sys/config.php';

class Model_VK {
    public $access_token, $v;
    const API = 'https://api.vk.com/method/';
    public function __construct($access_token, $v){
        $this->access_token = $access_token;
        $this->v = $v;
    }

    public function uploadImage($file, $group_id = null, $album_id = null){
        list($params['group_id'], $params['album_id']) = [$group_id, $album_id];
        $upl = $this->vk('photos.getUploadServer', $params)->response->upload_url;
        if (isset($upl)) {
            $upload = json_decode($this->curl($upl, ['file1' => new CURLFile($file)]));

            if (isset($upload->server)) {
                $photo = $this->vk('photos.save', [
                      'server'      => $upload->server,
                      'photos_list' => $upload->photos_list,
                      'album_id'    => $album_id,
                      'hash'        => $upload->hash,
                      'group_id'    => $group_id
                ]);   
                //print "<pre>"; print_r($photo);
                return $photo;

            }   
- ПРОБОВАЛ СЮДА
        }          
- ПРОБОВАЛ СЮДА
    }
- ПРОБОВАЛ СЮДА


    public function vk($method, $params){
        list($params['access_token'], $params['v']) = [$this->access_token, $this->v];
        return json_decode($this->curl(self::API . $method, $params));
    }

    public function curl($url, $params = false) {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        if (isset($params)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        }
        $upd = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $upd;
    }

}


$new = new Model_VK(mc_decrypt($_SESSION['UserInfo']['master_token'], ENCRYPTION_KEY), $System['api']['version']);
$new->uploadImage($ThisImg, $GroupID, $AlbumID); // адрес фото / id группы / id альбома

print "<pre>"; 
print_r($photo);
```

Comment: `return $photo;`

Comment: как бы не работает так %)
я попробовал написать return $photo сразу после //print "<pre>"; print_r($photo);

ничего не отображается, если за пределами класса попробовать вызвать объект...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оказывается все просто, нужно было заменить

```
$new->uploadImage($ThisImg, $GroupID, $AlbumID);
```

на

```
$photo = $new->uploadImage($ThisImg, $GroupID, $AlbumID);
```

и работать уже с массивом/объектом $photo